# How to use the character 'd' as it is inside a date format in Android

Tags: android, date, formatting, format, date-format

I'm using android.text.format.DateFormat to format a date as follows:

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat.format("EEEE dd de MMMM");
```

I need something like this (in spanish)
"Sunday 10 de June" for example, but the letter 'd' in the word 'de' is interpretted as the day in the format, y tried with this format "EEEE dd \de MMMM" and I get:
"Sunday 10 e June", missing the 'd'. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose `de` in single quotes like this: `"EEEE dd 'de' MMMM"`, as documented in the [javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
        "EEEE dd 'de' MMMM" , 
        Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ) 
    )
)
```

> martes 13 de febrero

## java.time

The [Answer by Robby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225718/642706) is correct, but both it and the Question refer to troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Specify [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine the human language used for name of day & month.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE dd 'de' MMMM" , Locale.CANADA ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Tuesday 13 de February

For the Canadian-French version:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE dd 'de' MMMM" , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> mardi 13 de février

Spanish:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ) ;  // Spanish in Spain.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE dd 'de' MMMM" , locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> martes 13 de febrero

### Automatically localize

You can avoid hard-coding such localization. Let java.time automatically localize.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

  DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
  String output = zdt.format( f ) ;

> mardi 13 février 2018

For Spanish in Spain:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ) ;  // Spanish in Spain. ;
for ( FormatStyle style : EnumSet.allOf( FormatStyle.class ) )
{
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( style  ).withLocale( locale ) ;
    String output = zdt.format( f );
    System.out.println(style + " | " + output );
}
```

> FULL | martes, 13 de febrero de 2018
>
> LONG | 13 de febrero de 2018
>
> MEDIUM | 13 feb. 2018
>
> SHORT | 13/2/18

By the way, understand that `Locale` and time zone have *nothing* to do with one another, completely orthogonal. The locale is for presentation translation/formatting. The time zone determines the wall-clock used in the content of the date-time value. You can have a moment in `Europe/Paris` time zone presented in Japanese language (locale), for example.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).